# Ошибка "TypeError: symbol is not a function at String (<anonymous>)" при использовании Jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, jest, leafletjs

Всем доброго дня. Есть приложение с картографией. Задача протестировать компонент отрисовки карты. В проекте используются React, Redux и Jest. Код теста:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import MapLayout from '../pages/Layout/MapLayout';
import directionsInfo from './mocks/mocksForMapLayoutTest';
import reducers from './utilsTest/renderWithProviders';

let container = null;

beforeEach(() => {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  container.classList.add('wrapper');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});

// eslint-disable-next-line jest/expect-expect
it('map rendered', () => {
  const initialState = {
    mapSearch: {
      zoom: 5,
    },
  };
  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState);
  const mapLayout = (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MapLayout directionsInfo={directionsInfo} mapUpdate={false} />, container);
    </Provider>
  );

  render(mapLayout);

  screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL();

  //   expect(screen.getByLabelText('Направление')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Тест завершается с ошибкой " TypeError: symbol is not a function at String ()"
Пробовал дебажить. Проверяемый компонент MapLayout запрашивает данные в stor, рендерит карту при помощи библиотеки leafLet и строит маршрут при помощи leafLet Routing Mashin.
При дебаге видно что тест падает при попытке отрендерить маршрут между токами при помощи компонента который реализует leafLet Routing Mashin.
Прошу помощи в решении проблемы.
Если нужно прикреплю код компонентов.

Comment: не надо «прикреплять код компонентов». надо привести [mcve].

Comment: Эксперимент показал, что если при отрисовке иконок в roating-mashin в L.marker(icon: house) в house передать SVG тест падает, а если передать PNG файл то тест проходит проверку, то есть компонент рендерится в тестовой среде. Где можно посмотреть причину этого?

Comment: aleksandr barakin с вашим комментарием абсолютно согласен. Но пока жалко времени. Обязательно последую вашему совету если не удастся решить проблему други путем.

Answer (score 1):

Всем доброго дня. Проблема была решена установкой
@testing-library/jest-dom" and eslint-plugin-jest-dom.